# New tag for (video) games?

Tags: discussion, tags

I saw that we repeatedly get questions about Japanese from video games. I think it might be useful to create a tag for such questions, as grammar/usage/vocabulary of Japanese can be different from Japanese from other sources.

I tagged three questions with [gaming](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gaming), but maybe [video-games](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-games) is a better name...?

In any case, I would like to ask for some feedback before introducing a new tag.

Answer (score 3):

The tag [video-games](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-games) is now live and [gaming](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gaming) is a tag synonym.

The tag excerpt currently reads

> ゲーム. Japanese grammar, expressions, vocabulary as used in the context of video games.

Of course comments are still welcome.

Comment: Might not be big enough to warrant a separate tag, but I'd suggest that the words used (by players) in `gaming` are different from the words used *in-game* for `video-games`

Comment: @Mars I changed it to "used in the context of video games", which should include gaming. Is this better?

Comment: I think so! Hard to distinguish between gaming terms and net-slang sometimes